# Workaround for the callout restriction in a Trigger Context

Tags: apex, trigger, callout

I have a specific requirement where the addresses of the Leads need to be first validated and then to check, if it is one of the countries that we as a company serve or not.

If we don't serve it we would close it right away.

I know I can implement this via future callouts, but this means, that somehow I should update them again, and as a result having a loop of triggers, which I want to avoid.

Any other workaround there known for similar cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your trigger, simply don't call the future method if you're already in a future method:

```
if(!System.isFuture()) {
  UtilMethods.doLeadCallout(Trigger.newMap.keySet());
}
```

Of course, if you're only triggering on insert, then you don't have to worry about recursive loops, because the trigger won't fire on update.